# Database layer/network for routing and closest facility option using ArcGIS Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis-pro, network-analyst, route, network-dataset, railroad

I am new to the use of ArcGIS Pro Network Analyst and trying to see if there is a way I can use the *route* option to calculate the walking or/and driving time between sets of points. Specifically, I need to know if the starting point and the endpoint (a railway/tube) are the possible shortest time or closest facility. Additionally, if not, how many stations have been skipped to get from a to b (e.g. from a location to closest rail/tube and how many stops have I walked past to get to my end point).

I already have all the points in a layer (both start-locations, end-locations and stations) and I also have a road layer with all roads/highways in the UK.

I am confused about how to actually build the necessary layer for the Network Analyst or if there is another way to do that, like a GB or UK dataset for Network Analyst that I can access and use (and licenced for use in a report/publication).

I have looked at two [training](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=agS1Fzq04l4&t=489s) [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKjBMeNWrn4&t=48s) but I still can't understand how to go around this.

Comment: Since you say you're open to another way, like a GB or UK dataset -- can you simply use ArcGIS Online to perform the route? In ArcGIS Pro > Analysis > Ready to Go tools > you can __Find Routes__.

Comment: To compliment @KHibma comment you could also explore using the Google Directions API but that requires some scripting in python.

Comment: @KHibma I already tried and I cannot do it... it gives me the "Tool has failed to open: C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcToolBox\Toolboxes\ReadyToUseServiceTools.tbx\FindRoutes"; I also do not credits to do it online

Comment: @Hornbydd I wish I knew how to use python ... :( any ideas if there are some "easy" way to do that? i have some R experience so maybe i could try that out, but i have never used api